# Rails HAML engine rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rendering, haml

What is wrong here?

```
Haml::Engine.new('= image_tag("golfer.png")').render
```

image_tag is always undefined (ActionView::Helpers in not loaded).
How can I fix that? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

```
  class TagHelper
    include Singleton
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
  end

  puts Haml::Engine.new('= image_tag("golfer.png")').render(TagHelper.instance)
```

Comment: Have you tried this with Rails 3?  I can not get this to work