# Using rails methods with Haml::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rake, haml

I want to have a rake task that reads a HAML file and creates a static html file out of it. The reason for this is that I want to dynamically localize my error pages in a manner described here http://devcorner.mynewsdesk.com/2010/01/13/rails-i18n-and-404500-error-pages/

Here is the method for writing the error pages.

```
def write_error_page(status, locale = nil)
  dest_filename = [status.to_s, locale, "html"].compact.join(".")
  File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "public", dest_filename), "w") do |file|
    path = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "views", "errors", "#{status}.haml")
    file.print Haml::Engine.new(File.read(path)).render
  end   
end
```

The problem is that Haml::Engine does not have rails methods available. So when a try to read the haml file, I get an error for every rails method in the file (I want to use methods 
like image_tag, form_for and obviously I18n.translate).

I noticed a similar issue that had been solved here: [Rails HAML engine rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097642/rails-haml-engine-rendering)

However, when I try the solution mentioned in the link above, I get the following error: "undefined local variable or method `config' for #".

How could I get the rails methods to work in the Haml::Engine so that I could read the HAML file? I also tried switching to ERB, but noticed that it leads to the same problem, which somebody else has at least partially resolved here [render erb from database into view problem please help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922469/render-erb-from-database-into-view-problem-please-help) But this solution didn't help me either.

I'm also open to other solutions than using Haml::Engine. I looked into capture_haml helper but don't see how that would help me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just now realized that I don't need Haml::Engine in this situation, because I'm in a rails environment so I can just call render. Silly me.

However, it's not completely trivial to call render from a rake task, because we are not in a controller or a view (and so rails purists even say that you should never do so, I think, but in this case it seems like the easiest way), so I post the code I used here (I used the approach mentioned here: http://wholemeal.co.nz/blog/2011/04/05/rendering-from-a-model-in-rails-3/).

```
def write_error_page(status, locale = nil)
  dest_filename = [status.to_s, locale, "html"].compact.join(".")
  File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "public", dest_filename), "w") do |file|
    path = File.join("app", "views", "errors", "#{status}.haml")
    file.print ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths.app.views.first).render(:file => path)
  end   
end
```

I had some problems with this approach too. For instance, form_for still didn't work properly (I want to have a feedback form on the error page) so I simply created the form with plain HTML (which you can luckily inject straight into .haml files). But the one thing from rails I needed to get to work in the .haml template - method I18n.translate - works like charm.

Comment: I'm trying to use this but Rails.configuration.paths.app.views.first it's giving an error undefined method `app' for #<Rails::Paths::Root:0x000000032ed968>... Can you help?

Comment: Resolved i used instead: Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first

Comment: Now other problem, i can't access the helpers methods, how can i inject that?

Comment: Resolved =) Before calling ActionView::Base.new just did: include ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `:environment` a dependency of your rake task:

```
task :some_task => :environment do
  # stuff here
end
```

This will load Rails.  It sounds like it's not been loaded.

Comment: Nope, that's not it. I call the write_error_pages method from this rake task:

  task :write_error_pages => :environment do
    ...
  end

I have rails methods in use in the write_error_page method, but not inside Haml::Engine, because Haml::Engine is a way to use Haml without dependency on rails. So in that sense it sounds like a wrong way to go, but I can't figure out any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this solution based on yours, once yours wasn't working for me, because of the views path, and because i needed to include some functions from my application helper. I think you can resolve the form_for problem including this: `ActionView::Base.send :include, ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper`

I change the format to html, because it was what i needed...

```
def to_html
  ActionView::Base.send :include, ActionView::Helpers::ApplicationHelper

  File.open(File.join(Rails.root, "public", 'test.html'), "w") do |file|

  file.print ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"].first).render(
                :partial => 'partial_folder/partial', 
                :format => :html,
                :locals => { :model => self}
              )
  end  
end
```